# Properties file isn't included in jar file when package Java application

Tags: java, netbeans

I have developed Java desktop application using Netbeans.
In my application, I used some properties files and I placed it under the Project folder so that I can access it by using code like that

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
```

But when I deploy and package my application to .jar file, I can't find out where properties files are and my application can not read value from properties files.

How can I fix that bug, and where should I place my properties file and load it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put it under `/src/resources/`, then use it like below.

```
ResourceBundle props = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.config");
```

NetBeans doesn't include the files under your project directory. Further, you need to build the project, in order to let NetBeans put the `properties` file inside your `/classes` directory. Then you should be able to pick it up, by running your application or just a particular related Java class.

Cheers.

Comment: I followed your guide, but program throw an exception
 java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name config, locale en_US
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1521)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1260)

Comment: Check out my addendum. Precisely, try this `ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources.config")`. Moreover, build the project before running any specific Java class.

Answer (score 3):

I started with ralphie boy's solution and it didn't work. Well, it would have worked if I had done what he said. Here's what I did and maybe it will add some useful detail.

I have always named my packages after the project, so I was not aware that in NetBeans there is *literally*, a package named `<default package>`. When I dragged my config.properties file up to the Source Packages level, low and behold a `<default package>` was made. It got placed in the src folder and built at the root in the dist .jar file.  After that, ralphie boy's solution was a cut and paste.

If you want your resource bundle or config file to be *in* the package, you have to include the path to it in the baseName string, like

```
ResourceBundle f = ResourceBundle.getBundle("pkgname/config");
```

or

```
ResourceBundle f = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com/mycompany/pkgname/config");
```

Answer (score 2):

To include a properties file that exists in the classpath (i.e. if it is somewhere under your /src directory when you build the jar file), you can use getResourceAsStream() like this:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));
```

Note the leading slash on the filename. You can also use this to get to files within different packages in your project.

```
properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/company/project/config.properties"));
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Java project, in the default package (i.e. .../src/), put this file: **messages.properties**

In your code, put this:

```
ResourceBundle f = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages");
```

This approach has the charming aspect that it actually works!

(Someone edited and civilized my original post, which had a lot of SCREAM in it. I was seeing some pretty invalid answers getting votes, which I haven't seen for a long time on this site.)