# Netbeans platform custom configuration file

Tags: java, configuration-files, netbeans-platform

I'm trying to create configuration file for database connection. Properties file would be best. This properties have to be changed after every application installation (customers database).

- I want this config file in the root of application (netbeans platform
  project, and distro folder). I can't find way how to refer to
  application root folder.
- I also find lack of documentation for FileUtil.getConfigFile/Root. I
  don't know where to find the configRoot (if it is even physical), or
  how to add ConfigFile offline (not in code, but just with copying
  config file).
- Tolerable solution woud be to add database configuration to system
  properties, but i can't find where to specify additional system properties
  in netbeans configuration files.

Comment: for now, i just solved it with ResourceBundle and propreties file placed in src folder.. (http://stackoverflow.com/q/2070065/606571) however this puts the props file in compiled jar and does not provide chance to change this file for end user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the properties file in a Release folder of one of your modules then access it with the InstalledFileLocator API: http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-modules/org/openide/modules/InstalledFileLocator.html

Comment: thank you for your response. I tried to use InstalledFileLocator. I moved my properties file into package root and then called locate(). i use properties file name as first argument, package bease (main package of plugin) as a second and  false (no localization). Is necessary to install plugin first? i need to try this in Nebeans ide durning development phase.

Comment: For more details check this from my book: http://wiki.netbeans.org/BookNBPlatformCookbookCH01#Retrieving_files_from_the_release_folder

Comment: With your book i was able to get my code work. In javadoc for `InstalledFileLocator` isn't specified, that the file shoul be in **`release`** folder . In y our cockbook it is. I put my properties file there and it works! **Thank you!**

Comment: Glad the book was useful! Feel free to take a look at the rest of the book!

Answer (score 1):

To access the the installation Directory of your NetBeans application you can use the following snippet

```
new File(System.getProperty ("netbeans.home")).getParentFile()
```

If you append `'/etc'` to the resultant file you will be in the the same folder that hosts the app.conf file.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can i add some file into /etc directiory? this directory isn't present before final build into zip file. I didn't find anything related to copy app.conf into this /etc file in ant's build.xml file.

Comment: @UltraMaster Include the file as a resource in your application, and then on first run place the file in the /etc directory

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [app.conf](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/support_for_custom_configuration_files)? It is located in ROOT/etc.

You could use system properties or, more elegant, an [OptionProcessor](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-sendopts/org/netbeans/spi/sendopts/OptionProcessor.html)

Comment: Thank you, for your response, but i dont want users to unintentionally change application settings, therefore i need to put database config into separate file, application root would be best, but /etc/ is also acceptable