# File missing when packaging to jar file

Tags: jar

I have a problem regarding exporting my Java project into a jar file.

I have this file (`application.properties`) which contains some database information and located under the project root directory.

There is no problem when running this project on Eclipse. But after exporting into a jar(Runnable Jar file) file, `application.properties` will not be included in the packaging and that cause the error.

Any suggestion how to fix this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126030/executable-jar-wont-find-the-properties-files.. Try to search before posting.

Comment: My project is a simple java/swing application. I don't use a maven resource plugin.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070065/properties-file-isnt-included-in-jar-file-when-package-java-application

Comment: and how are you reading the file? just follow the examples shown by @SenthilPrabhu

Comment: Put your `application.properties` file into a package, not to root directory.

Comment: @gibson: U r Welcomed

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have the `application.properties` reside *outside* the jar (for writing), or is it read-only? When outside you can have an initial template file in the jar, and copy it to some location.

```
//String applicationWorkingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir"); // The current constellation.
String userHomeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
File myApplicationDataDir = new File(userHomeDir + "/.MyApplication");
myApplicationDataDir.mkdir();
File propertiesFile = new File(myApplicationDataDir, "application.properties");
```

Also using the Preferences API instead of a properties would be a solution.